# Executable Files - how to identify them in ASCII

Tags: ascii, executable

It looks like all EXE files begin with MZ when they are opened in ASCII mode, is there an ASCII identified for vbs, com and bat files as well? i can't seem to find a pattern...

Or maybe there's another way to identify them? aside from just the extension...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really (Windows executables can have PE or PK at the beginning instead of MZ - [see this for other possible formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXE)).

For other types of files, there are certain heuristics you can use (e.g. GIF files start with "GIF89", Bash shell scripts usually start with `#!/bin/bash`, BAT files often execute `@echo off` at the beginning, VBS scripts use apostrophe at the start of line as a comment marker), but they aren't always 100% reliable (a file can be both a *BAT* script and a Bash shell script; or a file that's both a valid ZIP archive and a valid GIF image (like [that stegosaurus image](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/DeCSS/Gallery/Stego/index.html)), for example).

See e.g. [this article](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/File_Format_Identification) for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

[TrID](http://mark0.net/onlinetrid.aspx) seems to have a "standalone" application you could probably use and pass the file in and read the contents out and see what file it is. It prides itself on the ability to pass it a generic file (extension or without) and it uses the headers of the file to discover what file type it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

See if this tutorial is helpful ([How to detect the types of executable files 3 part series](http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=8)). He has even presented a step by step algorithm on how to do this.

Also see this post: [How to determine if a file is executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693891/how-to-determine-if-a-file-is-executable)