# Is there a way to call ShellFileGetInfo from C/C++ program?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I am new to Windows programming. Most of the examples which I found in the internet were of C# code. I am looking for C/C++ solution.

I am looking to find if a file is executable or not given its location and name of the file

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h> 
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "Shell32.lib") 

int main() {
     SHFILEINFOW sfi = { 0 };
     unsigned long* hr = SHGetFileInfoW("xyz.exe",
     FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE, &sfi, sizeof(sfi), SHGFI_EXETYPE);          
     if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
     { std::cout << "File has execute permission" << std::endl; }     
     return 0; }
```

Comment: What's wrong with the example in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetfileinfoa)?

Comment: The answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693891/how-to-determine-if-a-file-is-executable looks good; But it is in C#. After running it as a C++ program (with modification), I am unable to find the definition of SHGetFileInfo among others.

Comment: As the documentation says, the definition is in `<shellapi.h>`

Comment: @Vrajendra -- All the C# code does is call the Windows API function.  The code at the link has this: `[DllImport("shell32", EntryPoint = "SHGetFileInfo",...]` -- that indicates that C# is making the call to SHGetFileInfo.   To be honest, it is *more* difficult to get this to work in C# than it is in C or C++, as C or C++ need not jump through all of these hoops writing pinvoke declarations.

Comment: @paddy that's an answer. Just add a short example

Comment: No, there is no substitute for reading the documentation.  It's all there, including what you need to include, what you need to link against, how to invoke, etc.  Now, if the question was actually about a specific issue, perhaps an example would be useful.  As it stands, this reads as a question about how to effectively use search engines to find relevant information.

Comment: Thanks all for all the help. May be I should I have posted the code
```#include <shellapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "Shell32.lib")

int main() {
    SHFILEINFOW sfi = { 0 };
    unsigned long* hr = SHGetFileInfoW("xyz.exe",
        FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE,
        &sfi,
        sizeof(sfi),
        SHGFI_EXETYPE);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // The display name is now held in sfi.szDisplayName.
            std::cout << "File has execute permission" << std::endl;
        }
    //ILFree(pidl);
    return 0;
}```

Comment: I see a bunch of errors after running. SHFILEINFOW: undeclared identifier

Comment: @Vrajendra Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62869492/edit) the code into the question, not as a comment. Also, add an `#include <windows.h>` at the top.

Comment: "I see a bunch of errors" is a useless statement when asking for help.  Errors invariably contain critical information about the issue.  Even if you choose not to read them, you should never assume that nobody reads them.

Comment: I do not see you calling `CoInitialize` in this program.  Perhaps you didn't read the part of the docs that says _"You must initialize Component Object Model (COM) with CoInitialize or OleInitialize prior to calling SHGetFileInfo."_

Comment: Consider using cross-platform frameworks like [GTK](https://gtk.org/) or [Qt](https://qt.io/)